# Deleted everything before the dot

Tags: regex, notepad++

How can I use regex in notepad++ to make a query like this:
I have a list with subdomains containing three words such as

web1.com

test.web2.com

[www.test.web3.com](http://www.test.web3.com)

I want to filter so that only three words remain and something like this comes out:

web1.com

test.web2.com

test.web3.com

I was able to delete so that only the domain remains, but this is not what I want

```
^(?:.+\.)?([^.\r\n]+\.[^.\r\n]+)$
```

Comment: Just repeat the domain part 3 times with a dot between: `^([^.\r\n]+\.)?[^.\r\n]+\.[^.\r\n]+$`.

Answer (score 2):

An idea to match until the endpart starts and [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that.

```
^.*?\.([\w-]+\.[\w-]+\.[\w-]+)$
```

Replace with `$1` (what was captured by the first *group*)

- `.*?` matches [lazily](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) any amount of [any characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) (besides newline)
- `[\w-]+` [char-class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matches [one or more](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) [word characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) and hyphen

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/f8ikeA/1) (more explanation on the right side)
In Notepad++ be sure to have unchecked: [ ] *dot matches newline*

Answer (score 0):

Another take at it using a positive lookahead to assert the 3 "words" to the right, allowing for non whitespace chars excluding a dot using `[^\s.]`

In the replacement use an empty string.

```
^\S+?\.(?=[^\s.]+\.[^\s.]+\.[^\s.]+$)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D5fxKb/1).

[image]